# How to update an item in django without creating a new item?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

*I'm trying to update an item(book) present in the database, Even though I've added instance so that a new item is not created but instead the item is only updated, but unfortunately it's not working as it is supposed to, Instead of updating the item, a new item is being created, am I missing something in here?*

```
models.py

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    Language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to='images/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
    
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = " "
        return url
```

```
views.py

def book_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else :
            return render(request, 'crud_operation/book_form.html', {'form': form}) 
    else:
        form = BookForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'crud_operation/book_form.html',context)


def book_update(request,pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = BookForm(instance = book)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'crud_operation/book_form.html',context)
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('create-book/',views.book_register, name = 'books'),
    path('update-book/<int:pk>/',views.book_update, name = 'book_update'),
]
```

```
forms.py

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'published_on': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

Comment: What's in your `form.save()` method?

Comment: I resolved it, I was calling the 'books' in action on the book_form.html, so it was calling the create view url from the html page, once I removed it, it's working fine now.